# Hadoop on Batch System as a user process

Tags: hadoop, pbs, torque, sungridengine

I've seen Hadoop-on-Demand, and the Hadoop integration on SGE. My understanding is that requires admin privileges, which I don't have on the big cluster at work. The admins have their hands full and won't be able to set us up for months.

I recognizing the limits a transient virtual cluster puts on the the utility of HDFS. I also understand how using a lustre file system goes against the grain, but has anyone written either SGE or Torque (PBS) scripts to submit a job to a cluster that starts up a hadoop instance?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See MyHadoop: http://www.sdsc.edu/~allans/MyHadoop.pdf

Bad link. Article available here: http://archive.futuregrid.org/sites/default/files/myHadoop.pdf

Comment: also the Hadoop On Demand (HOD) scheduler in the distribution: 
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/hod_scheduler.html